# reg ex failing for leading GT sign

Tags: java, regex

I have the following reg ex and it failing to match and set to true?

```
String whatever = "> blah, blah, blah";
boolean q = Pattern.matches(whatever, "^>+");  // this evaluates to false
```

Am I matching correctly on the string?  What am I missing?  Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"^>+"` will match a sequence of one or more `>`. To match a string beginning with `>`, use:

```
whatever.matches(">.+");  // .+ after >
```

Use the [`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method rather than `Pattern.matches()`. The order of arguments in your method is incorrect. [`Pattern.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method takes regex as it's first argument. You're passing it as the 2nd argument.

Note that anchors are implicit while using regex while using the`matches()` method. You needn't provide them explicitly.